# Cross-database foreign key issue when database contains a dot(.) value

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, foreign-keys, laravel-migrations

I am facing an issue to assign across cross-databases relationship in laravel migration because my database name contains a dot(.) value,
My Database name is = "demo.local.com"

```
Schema::table('user_details', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')
            ->on('`demo.local.com`.users')
            ->onUpdate('RESTRICT')->onDelete('RESTRICT');
        });
```

I am using that way but its return  error like

> MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '.`com```.`users` (`id`) on delete RESTRICT on update RESTRICT

So it's possible to assign a foreign key when the database name contains a dot(.) value?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using dots rather than underscores?

Comment: Yes, I have used dots rather than underscores.

Comment: I understand that, but why have you chosen dots? The general consensus is to use underscores since it makes life much easier, which would be the quickest solution to this problem unless you are being forced to use dots for some reason?

Comment: We already have dots in existing databases. So we need to convert them to underscores if in case it is not working.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I would recommend, you can use table names with dots, but as far as I can tell laravel does not support this so you would have to use raw queries. My advice would be to rename your tables to use underscores instead of dots and this will make life much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution by using DB raw query and it's working for me

```
Schema::table('user_details', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')
            ->on(\DB::raw('`demo.local.com`.users'))
            ->onUpdate('RESTRICT')->onDelete('RESTRICT');
        });
```